# Can introspect be used only in first person ? Or better word to replace it, in following context

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Meaning of introspect is examine one's thoughts and feeling. In fact, i have to find word for "introspect". I m writing a technical report, can I use the word "introspect" but the meaning i want to make is "examine the information further in specific area and try to figure out something" ?

Comment: The term is [far more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=introspect%2Cintrospects%2Cintrospected%2Cintrospection&year_start=1860&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) used in its nominalized form, *introspection,* than as a finite verb.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean *inspect* (*to introspect*, like you said, can only mean to examine the thoughts in your own head — to "look into" yourself):

Definition & Example (via dictionary.com):

> to look carefully at or over; view closely and critically:
>
> *to inspect every part of the motor.*